Spring boot app login works but it doesnt secure the end points based on user role
So I am a beginner in spring boot, I litteraly have never worked with it or anything but i am doing an internship and they told i should use it and i have only 2 months(now  1 month), and everything is going good except the authorization, now it does sign in with data from database but it doesnt restrict certain end points like i configure in securityconfiuration class, i specified which role have acces to an endpoint but nothing, i really need help becuase i tried everything i am confused .
Securityconfig:
`
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private Jwtauthfilter jwt;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService, 
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder,Jwtauthfilter jwt) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.jwt = jwt;
    }

    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/employe/**").hasRole("Role_Employe")
            .requestMatchers("/manager/**").hasRole("Role_Manager")
            .requestMatchers("/rh/**").hasRole("Role_rh")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(jwt, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

}

`

CustomUserDetailsService class 

  
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeRepository rep;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Employe emp = rep.findByEmail(username);
        if (emp == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with email: " + username);
        }
        
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println(">>>>role:"+emp.getRole());
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(emp.getRole())); // Assuming Roles has a method to get the role name
        
        return new User(
                emp.getEmail(),
                emp.getMotdepass(),
                authorities
        );
      
    }

    private Collection<GrantedAuthority> mep(List<String> roles) {
        return roles.stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticate(AuthenticationConfiguration auth) throws Exception{
        return auth.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
   
}

`
JWTauthfilter class :
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Jwtauthfilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    final private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    final private JwtUtil jwt;

    @Autowired
    public Jwtauthfilter(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, JwtUtil jwt) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.jwt = jwt;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String userEmail;
        final String jwtToken;
        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        jwtToken = authHeader.substring(7);
        userEmail = jwt.extractUsername(jwtToken);
        
        // Debug log to check if the JWT token and user email are extracted correctly
        System.out.println("JWT Token: " + jwtToken);
        System.out.println("User Email: " + userEmail);

        if (userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails user = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
            if (jwt.validateToken(jwtToken, user)) {
                // Debug log to check if roles are being extracted from the JWT token
                System.out.println("User Authorities/Roles: " + user.getAuthorities());

                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, user.getAuthorities());
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

